# Forever-npm will not start my ExpressJS app

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, forever

I am trying to use forever so that I can assure that my ExpressJS app will remain running constantly.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Strangely, 'forever list' displays nothing, 'forever --version' displays nothing

I've tried:

```
forever start -c "npm start" ./
```

and:

```
forever start app.js
```

Without anything displayed.

Comment: What does `which forever` tell you?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/forever

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: What happens if you run `forever app.js`? Or `forever list`?

Comment: I installed it by "npm install forever -g"

&& Nothing is displayed when running the above.

Comment: What does `npm bin -g` tell you?

Comment: I've also tried running /usr/local/bin/forever and it doesn't work either.

Comment: See my last question. What does it tell?

Comment: $ npm bin -g
/usr/local/bin

Comment: Does `forever` return anything for any command?  Meaning can you get it to output `forever --help`?

Comment: 'forever --help' displays nothing

Comment: Then you might want to try [reinstalling it](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-uninstall.html), or at least viewing the `forever` file to see what's inside, and why this does nothing.  You could also try installing `forever` locally (not globally) and testing if you can execute the file there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node js with express framework then script will not start using :

```
forever start app.js
```

First stop all running apps:

```
forever stopall
```

When this Express framework used it must be started with:

```
forever start ./bin/www
```

and you should find this in package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  }
```

I hope it helps you.